# Keep rows which have two string in the same row

Tags: r

In a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), text = c("hi my name is E","hi what's your name","name here"))
```

I would like to keep row which contain both hi and name words in a row. Example of expended output:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), text = c("hi my name is E","hi what's your name"))
```

I try this but it doesn't work properly:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    filter(str_detect(text, 'name&hi'))
```

Answer (score 6):

One simple answer and two more complex answers you should really only need if you have more than 2 words to check

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(text, 'hi') & str_detect(text, 'name'))

df %>% 
  filter(rowSums(outer(text, c('hi', 'name'), str_detect)) == 2)

df %>% 
  filter(reduce(c('hi', 'name'), ~ .x & str_detect(text, .y), .init = TRUE))
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will filter things like `hihonames` which of course is not `hi` and `name`

Answer (score 4):

We can also use regex to specify whether 'hi' follows 'name' or (`|`) 'name' follows 'hi

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
     filter(str_detect(text, 'hi\\b.*\\bname|name\\b.*\\bhi'))
```

Comment: This has boundary. Correct

Answer (score 1):

in Base-R

```
f[grep(".*hi.*name.*",f$text),]
```

output

```
  id                text
1  1     hi my name is E
2  2 hi what's your name
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another `dplyr` and `stringr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 filter(lengths(str_match_all(text, "name|hi")) == 2)

  id                text
1  1     hi my name is E
2  2 hi what's your name
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 filter(all(c("name", "hi") %in% unlist(str_extract_all(text, "name|hi"))))
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 filter(str_count(text, "name|hi") == 2)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will filter things like `hihonames` which of course is not `hi` and `name`